# Why prolog fails to find a route to a vertices (in graph)?

Tags: prolog

I have a question to you:

I have an exercise that says:

Let there be given edges in the directed graph `arc (a, b)`, `arc (b, c)`, `arc (a, d)`, `arc (d, e)`, `arc (d, f)`, `arc (f, a)` and `arc (f, g)`. Test `go / 2`, `go1 / 3` predicates.
I need to know why Prolog answers false for the following query:

`? - go1 (a, b, X)`.

I have a graph illustrated below and a code pasted below.

[image: A graph image]

The code is here:

```
arc(a,b).%these are the edges.
arc(b,c).
arc(a,d).
arc(d,e).
arc(d,f).
arc(f,a).
arc(f,g).

go(X,X).
go(X,Y):-arc(X,Z),go(Z,Y).
% without arc(f,a):
% yes ?- go(a,c).
% no  ?- go(d,c).
% no  ?- go(f,a).
% yes ?- go(a,g).
%
% with arc(f,a):
% yes ?- go(a,c).
% out of local stack ?- go(a,g).

member1(H,[H|_]).
member1(H,[_|T]):-member1(H,T).

go1(X,X,_).
go1(X,Y,T):-arc(X,Z),not(member1(Z,[X|T])),go1(Z,Y,[X|T]).
% with arc(f,a):
% yes ?- go1(a,c,[]).
% yes ?- go1(a,g,[]).
```

So guys, please help me to figure out why it happens? Why does Prolog answer false for the following query:

`? - go1 (a, b, X)`.

I've tried to trace the query and I've gotten the answer that is below:

```
[trace]  ?- go1(a,b,X).
   Call: (8) go1(a, b, _982) ? creep
   Call: (9) arc(a, _1202) ? creep
   Exit: (9) arc(a, b) ? creep
^  Call: (9) not(member1(b, [a|_982])) ? creep
   Call: (10) member1(b, [a|_982]) ? creep
   Call: (11) member1(b, _982) ? creep
   Exit: (11) member1(b, [b|_1206]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) member1(b, [a, b|_1206]) ? creep
^  Fail: (9) not(user:member1(b, [a|_982])) ? creep
   Redo: (9) arc(a, _1202) ? creep
   Exit: (9) arc(a, d) ? creep
^  Call: (9) not(member1(d, [a|_982])) ? creep
   Call: (10) member1(d, [a|_982]) ? creep
   Call: (11) member1(d, _982) ? creep
   Exit: (11) member1(d, [d|_1206]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) member1(d, [a, d|_1206]) ? creep
^  Fail: (9) not(user:member1(d, [a|_982])) ? creep
   Fail: (8) go1(a, b, _982) ? creep
false.
```

Well, what I don't understand is why we have here the answer below:

```
 Exit: (11) member1(b, [b|_1206]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) member1(b, [a, b|_1206]) ? creep
^  Fail: (9) not(user:member1(b, [a|_982])) ? creep
```

Why does the Prolog not recognize that there is an edge from a to b? Why does it say that b is in the list that there is only [a] after all. Why does this call fail there? What's the reason of the query failure?

Comment: This graph illustration helps greatly, I find it always sadly missing in questions.

Answer (score 1):

You pass it a free variable `X`, so that means that the:

```
member(b, [a|X]).
```

call will succeed, indeed:

```
?- member(b, [a|X]).
X = [b|_2142] ;
X = [_2140, b|_2148] ;
X = [_2140, _2146, b|_2154]
```

Now `not(member(Z, [X|T]))` will succeed, given that the search of `member(Z, [X|T])` fails, but here it will always succeed, since a free variable can always be grounded to a list that contains `Z`, hence it fails.

If you call it with:

```
go1 (a, b, [])
```

it will succeed, since then `member(b, [a])` will indeed fail.

You can define a predicate that will reconstruct the path with:

```
go1(A, B, P) :-
    go1(A, B, P, []).

go1(A, A, [A], _).
go1(A, C, [A|T], V) :-
    arc(A, B),
    \+ member(B, [A|V]),
    go1(B, C, T, [A|V]).
```

and thus call it with `go1(A, B, P)` to obtain the path `P`.

Comment: So this means that we can use the empty list but not a variable to make this thing work. Am I right?

Comment: Okay. I get it. Thank you very much Willem. ;)